# Match a pattern in a field and replace the field with another

Tags: arrays, awk, split

I have the following file:

```
A T ./. 0/1 1/1
C G ./. 1/1 ./.
```

I want to transform it to:

```
A  T  A A A T T T
C  G  C C G G C C
```

I first split the file as follows

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if(/\//){split($i, a, "\/"); $i=a[1]" "a[2]} }}1' file
```

Next step, I need to do the following written as pseudocode:
`a[1]` and `a[2]` are the elements of the array `(a)` from the code above:

```
if a[1]==a[2]=="." then write $1 instead for both
if a[1]=="0" then write $1
if a[2]=="1" then write $2
```

how can I obtain this in awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F"[/ ]" '{for( i=3;i<=NF;i++){if ($i==0 || $i==".")$i=$1;else if($i==1) $i=$2}};1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[ /]+' '{a[0]=a["."]=a[$1]=$1; a[1]=a[$2]=$2; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",a[$i],(i==NF?ORS:OFS)}' file
A T A A A T T T
C G C C G G C C
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[ /]+'`

  This sets the field separator to one or more of space or `/`.
- `a[0]=a["."]=a[$1]=$1; a[1]=a[$2]=$2`

  This assigns values to associative array `a` based on the values of the first two fields.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",a[$i],(i==NF?ORS:OFS)`

  For each field, `i`, this prints out the value of `a[$i]`.

  The combination `i==NF?ORS:OFS` is *ternary statement*.  If we are on the last field, that is, if `i==NF`, then this returns the output record separator, `ORS`.  If not, it returns the output field separator, `OFS`.